Is a boundary of a completely invariant set is still completely invariant under an analytic function?
$R(z)$ is a rational function from the extended plane to the extended plane.
Consider $D$ is a union of components of the Fatou set of $R(z)$,
If $D$ is completely invariant, then how to prove that the boundary $\partial D$ is completely invariant?
(A set $D$ is called completely invariant under the function $R(z)$, if $f^{-1}(D)=D=f(D)$  )

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
